# jQuery .each only working on first element in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples) in a bootstrap carousel.  I've got it working properly on the first image in the carousel using a jQuery .each function, but it's not working properly on any of the subsequent images.  It seems it will only work on the item that is "active" when the page loads.

Here is the HTML for my carousel:

```
<div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide'>
    <div class='carousel-outer'>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
          <div class='item active'>
            <span></span>
            <a href="images/large/product-image01.png" data-fancybox><img id="image_01" class="img-responsive" src='images/product-image.png' data-zoom-image="images/large/product-image01.png" alt='' /></a>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
          <span></span>
            <a href="images/large/product-image02.png" data-fancybox><img id="image_02" class="img-responsive" src='images/product-image.png' data-zoom-image="images/large/product-image02.png" alt='' /></a>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <a href="images/large/product-image03.png" data-fancybox><img id="image_03" class="img-responsive" src='images/product-image.png' data-zoom-image="images/large/product-image03.png" alt='' />
          </div>  
          <div class='item'>
            <a href="images/large/product-image04.png" data-fancybox><img id="image_04" class="img-responsive" src='images/product-image.png' data-zoom-image="images/large/product-image04.png"alt='' />
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
        </a>
      </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
      <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'><img src='images/item-thumb.png' alt='' /></li>
      <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='1'><img src='images/item-thumb.png' alt='' /></li>
      <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='2'><img src='images/item-thumb.png' alt='' /></li>
      <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='3'><img src='images/item-thumb.png' alt='' /></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And here is the code from my external javascript file.  I've included this right before my closing  tag, as it would not work in the header.  Also of note, it does not seem to work at all if I use $(document).ready.

```
$('.carousel-inner .item a img').each(function(){
    $(this).elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
});
```

I'd appreciate any help understanding why this is only working on the first image in my carousel.

**EDIT:**
I also tried manually selecting each image, but it still only works for the one image that is loaded when the page loads:

```
$("#image_01").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
    $("#image_02").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
    $("#image_03").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
    $("#image_04").elevateZoom({
        zoomType: "inner",
        cursor: "crosshair"
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `.each()`? Try just `$('.carousel-inner .item a img').elevateZoom(...)`

Comment: Just tried that and doesn't work even on the first image with that code unfortunately.

Comment: It makes no sense that this works at the end of the HTML, but not in `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to loop through all images in carousel-inner class try this...

```
$('.carousel-inner img').each(...
```

or

```
$('.carousel-inner').find(img).each(...
```

Comment: The first of these two is what the OP already has in their question near the end. How does this answer their question?

Comment: I tried changing the selector as you stated, but continue to have the same issue. I don't think it's an issue with the selector but rather it seems to only recognize the element that loads with the page.